# jquery help with back to top

Tags: javascript, jquery

why is this not working?

```
<script type="text/javascript">     
jQuery.noConflict();

jQuery(document).ready(function(){
   if( jQuery(".page").height() < jQuery(window).height() ) {
       jQuery(".backtop").hide();
   }
   else {
       jQuery(".backtop").show();
   }
});
</script>
```

I'm using two frameworks, mootools and jquery. I don't know how to use mootools and it must be there. I know a little of jquery and just want the "back to top" button to appear when the body (.page) is bigger than the window.

Can anybody help me???

**EDIT: CAN ANYONE GIVE ME A MOOTOOLS SIMILAR SCRIPT?????**

Comment: have you tried `if(jQuery(document).height() < jQuery(window).height()) { ... }`?

Comment: The only things I can recommend now are to print (with `console.log()`) `jQuery(".page").height()` and `jQuery(window).height()` __OR__ create a test page with Mootools removed. There's a slight but possible chance of a conflict between the two libraries.

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/yyEPR/

This code works.I copied the code from http://briancray.com/2009/10/06/scroll-to-top-link-jquery-css/

Answer (score 0):

Is .backtop a class or the id of the element?  to access the id try $("#backtop").hide();

Good luck and HTH.
-- Joe